# What is the value of $ 1+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6} + \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9} +\dots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

The infinite sum

$$ 1+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6} + \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9} + \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12} +\dots $$
is

a.) $2^{1/2}$

b.) $3^{1/2}$

c.) $ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/2} $

d.) $ \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1/2} $

My Approach: I initially tried to write the general term of the following expansion but couldn't do so due to the fact that number of components in product change with each term.

I tried using the partial fractions but couldn't proceed with it much further.

In the final attempt I tried grouping the terms successively in pairs of two, and then trying to add them , that too however proved futile.

I am looking for a method to solve the above question, as well as a more general line of approach for the following type of questions.

Comment: Although the question is duplicate which I didn't know , Here I am looking to find a more general way of solving these kinds of problems as well. This means that the answer of the previous question might not give me the information that I am searching for . Should I delete the question regardless ?